# how can add keyboard layout to docker container?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

i want to add keyboard layout to my docker images that based on ubuntu.

i try `setxkbmap -layout us,ir -variant ,pes_keypad` and layout added successful but the numeric keys that exist top of keywrite area dosnt work

or shift keys pressed befor numeric key

for example i press 9 key but the out put is this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17KKs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this :

edit `evdev` file that is in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/` and replace that to my custom file

my custom evdev :

```
// translation from evdev scancodes to something resembling xfree86 keycodes.

default xkb_keycodes "evdev" {
minimum = 8;
maximum = 255;

# Added for pc105 compatibility
<LSGT> = 94;

<TLDE> = 49;
key <AE01> {[ 1,     exclam,         bar, onesuperior   ]};
key <AE02> {[ 2,  backslash,          at, twosuperior   ]};
key <AE03> {[ 3, numbersign,  asciitilde, threesuperior ]};
key <AE04> {[ 4,     dollar,    EuroSign, onequarter    ]};
key <AE05> {[ 5,    percent,     onehalf, fiveeighths   ]};
key <AE06> {[ 6,  ampersand,     notsign, threequarters ]};
key <AE07> {[ 7,      slash,   backslash, seveneighths  ]};
key <AE08> {[ 8,  parenleft,   oneeighth, threeeighths  ]};
key <AE09> {[ 9, parenright, asciicircum                ]};
key <AE10> {[ 0,      equal,   copyright                ]};

<TAB> = 23;
<AD01> = 24;
<AD02> = 25;
<AD03> = 26;
<AD04> = 27;
<AD05> = 28;
<AD06> = 29;
<AD07> = 30;
<AD08> = 31;
<AD09> = 32;
<AD10> = 33;
<AD11> = 34;
<AD12> = 35;
<BKSL> = 51;
alias <AC12> = <BKSL>;
<RTRN> = 36;

<CAPS> = 66;
<AC01> = 38;
<AC02> = 39;
<AC03> = 40;
<AC04> = 41;
<AC05> = 42;
<AC06> = 43;
<AC07> = 44;
<AC08> = 45;
<AC09> = 46;
<AC10> = 47;
<AC11> = 48;

<LFSH> = 50;
<AB01> = 52;
<AB02> = 53;
<AB03> = 54;
<AB04> = 55;
<AB05> = 56;
<AB06> = 57;
<AB07> = 58;
<AB08> = 59;
<AB09> = 60;
<AB10> = 61;
<RTSH> = 62;

<LALT> = 64;
<LCTL> = 37;
<SPCE> = 65;
<RCTL> = 105;
<RALT> = 108;
// Microsoft keyboard extra keys
<LWIN> = 133;
<RWIN> = 134;
<COMP> = 135;
alias <MENU> = <COMP>;

<ESC> = 9;
<FK01> = 67;
<FK02> = 68;
<FK03> = 69;
<FK04> = 70;
<FK05> = 71;
<FK06> = 72;
<FK07> = 73;
<FK08> = 74;
<FK09> = 75;
<FK10> = 76;
<FK11> = 95;
<FK12> = 96;

<PRSC> = 107;
// <SYRQ> = 107;
<SCLK> = 78;
<PAUS> = 127;
// <BRK> = 419;

<INS> = 118;
<HOME> = 110;
<PGUP> = 112;
<DELE> = 119;
<END> = 115;
<PGDN> = 117;

<UP> = 111;
<LEFT> = 113;
<DOWN> = 116;
<RGHT> = 114;

<NMLK> = 77;
<KPDV> = 106;
<KPMU> = 63;
<KPSU> = 82;

<KP7> = 79;
<KP8> = 80;
<KP9> = 81;
<KPAD> = 86;

<KP4> = 83;
<KP5> = 84;
<KP6> = 85;

<KP1> = 87;
<KP2> = 88;
<KP3> = 89;
<KPEN> = 104;

<KP0> = 90;
<KPDL> = 91;
<KPEQ> = 125;

<FK13> = 191;
<FK14> = 192;
<FK15> = 193;
<FK16> = 194;
<FK17> = 195;
<FK18> = 196;
<FK19> = 197;
<FK20> = 198;
<FK21> = 199;
<FK22> = 200;
<FK23> = 201;
<FK24> = 202;

// Keys that are generated on Japanese keyboards

//<HZTG> =  93; // Hankaku/Zenkakau toggle - not actually used
alias <HZTG> = <TLDE>;
<HKTG> = 101;   // Hiragana/Katakana toggle
<AB11> = 97;    // backslash/underscore
<HENK> = 100;   // Henkan
<MUHE> = 102;   // Muhenkan
<AE13> = 132;   // Yen
<KATA> =  98;   // Katakana
<HIRA> =  99;   // Hiragana
<JPCM> = 103;   // KPJPComma
//<RO>   =  97; // Romaji

// Keys that are generated on Korean keyboards

<HNGL> = 130;   // Hangul Latin toggle
<HJCV> = 131;   // Hangul to Hanja conversion

// Solaris compatibility

alias <LMTA> = <LWIN>;
alias <RMTA> = <RWIN>;
<MUTE> = 121;
<VOL-> = 122;
<VOL+> = 123;
<POWR> = 124;
<STOP> = 136;
<AGAI> = 137;
<PROP> = 138;
<UNDO> = 139;
<FRNT> = 140;
<COPY> = 141;
<OPEN> = 142;
<PAST> = 143;
<FIND> = 144;
<CUT>  = 145;
<HELP> = 146;

// Extended keys that may be generated on "Internet" keyboards.
// evdev has standardize names for these.

<LNFD> = 109;   // #define KEY_LINEFEED            101
<I120> = 120;   // #define KEY_MACRO               112
<I126> = 126;   // #define KEY_KPPLUSMINUS         118
<I128> = 128;   // #define KEY_SCALE               120
<I129> = 129;   // #define KEY_KPCOMMA             121
<I147> = 147;   // #define KEY_MENU                139
<I148> = 148;   // #define KEY_CALC                140
<I149> = 149;   // #define KEY_SETUP               141
<I150> = 150;   // #define KEY_SLEEP               142
<I151> = 151;   // #define KEY_WAKEUP              143
<I152> = 152;   // #define KEY_FILE                144
<I153> = 153;   // #define KEY_SENDFILE            145
<I154> = 154;   // #define KEY_DELETEFILE          146
<I155> = 155;   // #define KEY_XFER                147
<I156> = 156;   // #define KEY_PROG1               148
<I157> = 157;   // #define KEY_PROG2               149
<I158> = 158;   // #define KEY_WWW                 150
<I159> = 159;   // #define KEY_MSDOS               151
<I160> = 160;   // #define KEY_COFFEE              152
<I161> = 161;   // #define KEY_DIRECTION           153
<I162> = 162;   // #define KEY_CYCLEWINDOWS        154
<I163> = 163;   // #define KEY_MAIL                155
<I164> = 164;   // #define KEY_BOOKMARKS           156
<I165> = 165;   // #define KEY_COMPUTER            157
<I166> = 166;   // #define KEY_BACK                158
<I167> = 167;   // #define KEY_FORWARD             159
<I168> = 168;   // #define KEY_CLOSECD             160
<I169> = 169;   // #define KEY_EJECTCD             161
<I170> = 170;   // #define KEY_EJECTCLOSECD        162
<I171> = 171;   // #define KEY_NEXTSONG            163
<I172> = 172;   // #define KEY_PLAYPAUSE           164
<I173> = 173;   // #define KEY_PREVIOUSSONG        165
<I174> = 174;   // #define KEY_STOPCD              166
<I175> = 175;   // #define KEY_RECORD              167
<I176> = 176;   // #define KEY_REWIND              168
<I177> = 177;   // #define KEY_PHONE               169
<I178> = 178;   // #define KEY_ISO                 170
<I179> = 179;   // #define KEY_CONFIG              171
<I180> = 180;   // #define KEY_HOMEPAGE            172
<I181> = 181;   // #define KEY_REFRESH             173
<I182> = 182;   // #define KEY_EXIT                174
<I183> = 183;   // #define KEY_MOVE                175
<I184> = 184;   // #define KEY_EDIT                176
<I185> = 185;   // #define KEY_SCROLLUP            177
<I186> = 186;   // #define KEY_SCROLLDOWN          178
<I187> = 187;   // #define KEY_KPLEFTPAREN         179
<I188> = 188;   // #define KEY_KPRIGHTPAREN        180
<I189> = 189;   // #define KEY_NEW                 181
<I190> = 190;   // #define KEY_REDO                182
<I208> = 208;   // #define KEY_PLAYCD              200
<I209> = 209;   // #define KEY_PAUSECD             201
<I210> = 210;   // #define KEY_PROG3               202
<I211> = 211;   // #define KEY_PROG4               203 conflicts with AB11
<I212> = 212;   // #define KEY_DASHBOARD           204
<I213> = 213;   // #define KEY_SUSPEND             205
<I214> = 214;   // #define KEY_CLOSE               206
<I215> = 215;   // #define KEY_PLAY                207
<I216> = 216;   // #define KEY_FASTFORWARD         208
<I217> = 217;   // #define KEY_BASSBOOST           209
<I218> = 218;   // #define KEY_PRINT               210
<I219> = 219;   // #define KEY_HP                  211
<I220> = 220;   // #define KEY_CAMERA              212
<I221> = 221;   // #define KEY_SOUND               213
<I222> = 222;   // #define KEY_QUESTION            214
<I223> = 223;   // #define KEY_EMAIL               215
<I224> = 224;   // #define KEY_CHAT                216
<I225> = 225;   // #define KEY_SEARCH              217
<I226> = 226;   // #define KEY_CONNECT             218
<I227> = 227;   // #define KEY_FINANCE             219
<I228> = 228;   // #define KEY_SPORT               220
<I229> = 229;   // #define KEY_SHOP                221
<I230> = 230;   // #define KEY_ALTERASE            222
<I231> = 231;   // #define KEY_CANCEL              223
<I232> = 232;   // #define KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN      224
<I233> = 233;   // #define KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP        225
<I234> = 234;   // #define KEY_MEDIA               226
<I235> = 235;   // #define KEY_SWITCHVIDEOMODE     227
<I236> = 236;   // #define KEY_KBDILLUMTOGGLE      228
<I237> = 237;   // #define KEY_KBDILLUMDOWN        229
<I238> = 238;   // #define KEY_KBDILLUMUP          230
<I239> = 239;   // #define KEY_SEND                231
<I240> = 240;   // #define KEY_REPLY               232
<I241> = 241;   // #define KEY_FORWARDMAIL         233
<I242> = 242;   // #define KEY_SAVE                234
<I243> = 243;   // #define KEY_DOCUMENTS           235
<I244> = 244;   // #define KEY_BATTERY             236
<I245> = 245;   // #define KEY_BLUETOOTH           237
<I246> = 246;   // #define KEY_WLAN                238
<I247> = 247;   // #define KEY_UWB                 239
<I248> = 248;   // #define KEY_UNKNOWN             240
<I249> = 249;   // #define KEY_VIDEO_NEXT          241
<I250> = 250;   // #define KEY_VIDEO_PREV          242
<I251> = 251;   // #define KEY_BRIGHTNESS_CYCLE    243
<I252> = 252;   // #define KEY_BRIGHTNESS_ZERO     244
<I253> = 253;   // #define KEY_DISPLAY_OFF         245
<I254> = 254;   // #define KEY_WWAN                246
<I255> = 255;   // #define KEY_RFKILL              247

// Fake keycodes for virtual keys
<LVL3> =   92;
<MDSW> =   203;
<ALT>  =   204;
<META> =   205;
<SUPR> =   206;
<HYPR> =   207;

indicator 1  = "Caps Lock";
indicator 2  = "Num Lock";
indicator 3  = "Scroll Lock";
indicator 4  = "Compose";
indicator 5  = "Kana";
indicator 6  = "Sleep";
indicator 7  = "Suspend";
indicator 8  = "Mute";
indicator 9  = "Misc";
indicator 10 = "Mail";
indicator 11 = "Charging";

alias <ALGR> = <RALT>;

// For Brazilian ABNT2
alias <KPPT> = <I129>;
};

// PC98
xkb_keycodes "pc98" {
include "evdev(evdev)"
};
```

then i try to add my layout by `setxkbmap` like this :

```
setxkbmap -keycodes evdev -layout ir,us -variant pes_keypad, -option keypad:legacy,grp:toggle
```

indeed i map the numeric key  to numpad

[about xkb configs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3A%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions/ht)